# In the browser, how to print on pre-printed paper with layout accuracy?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web, printing

I have an AngularJS app that is required to print data over some 'official' pre-printed papers.

I have a form/report generated by my application. I want to give the user the tools to **visually** and accurately adjust the 'elements' so they can accurately get printed on pre-printed papers, without all the 'extra' HTML/CSS. (So no borders, no colors,  ... only data).

The user changes need to be persisted and reused in the future.

**Update**
So, by Visually, I mean a 'designer' that a user can drag 'data-bounded' elements  like "Firstname", "Lastname" ... etc, to an electronic White-paper.

Comment: In HTML perspective, you can use `mm` or `cm` along with `position: fixed` or `position: absolute` in print CSS, in order to get the accurate result of position. However, when sending to print, user must choose "No Scale" (not "Fit to Scale") in order to have correct results.

Comment: How can a user do this visually, like drag, resize ?

Comment: @JalalEl-Shaer for features like drag and drop consider html5 and js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use CSS unit as `cm, mm, in, pt, pc` in media query for print so you can set sizes which match your paper template.

```
@media print { 
 /* All your print styles go here use unit as cm here */
 #header, #footer, #nav { display: none !important; } 
}
```

Regarding page/element behavior you could use JavaScript and HTML5.
A [tutorial/info](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/) here.

Comment: How can a user do this visually, like drag, resize ?

Comment: @JalalEl-Shaer for drag you can have a look at html5 `draggable` https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/

Comment: @JalalEl-Shaer What to you mean by visually? You'd have to program the tools with html/javascript have a look e.g. [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events)

Comment: @GibboK great link by the way. I have updated my question.

Comment: @GibboK can you improve your answer a bit , so I mark it as so ?

Comment: @JalalEl-Shaer I edited my answer, please do not forget to accept it if you have found it useful :). Thanks for your time.